# Show transparent color highlight on a View when clicking it

Tags: android

So. You know how when you click a post in the Google+ app, the entire View becomes blue. I want to do that as well, but with an ImageView.

I have the following code snippet, setting the actual image as the background and the selector as the main resource. This looks good, but doesn't respect scaleType for the background image:

```
      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/painting_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/img"
            android:src="@drawable/selector"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

By the way, `@drawable/selector` is just a selector that shows a tranparent color for `state_pressed`:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#44521400" />
    </shape></item>
```

How can I make this work while respecting the scaleType?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap your `ImageView` in a `FrameLayout`, and define the `FrameLayout` to be clickable. Be careful to assign the onClick event to the `FrameLayout`, and not to the `ImageView`, or the effect will break! Also note that `foreground` has been set to a selector, not `background`.

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="@drawable/imagebutton_selector" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/painting_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Makes sense... It's even better!

Comment: for example, imagebutton_selector.xml:    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/selected"/>
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/pressed"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/bg_window"/>
</selector>`

Answer (score 1):

ScaleType is only applied to the src drawable, not the background. Consider using the second option with an overlay view where you'll be implementing the click action, like this:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/painting_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/imagebutton_selector"
            android:onClick="onImageClick" />
     </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion! But I already answered my own question. I forgot to set the onClick event to the wrapping `FrameLayout`; it was still defined for the `ImageView`.